Why does the flex-container extend beyond the viewport width? I see the horizontal scrollbar in mobile phone vertical view?
I have this page:


:root {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.15;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar"
    "main";
  
}

.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.main {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: main;
  
}

.main ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box1 {
  background: blue;
}

.box2 {
  background: green;
}

.box3 {
  background: orchid;
}

.box4 {
  background: red;
}


@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 200px 500px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "sidebar main";
  }
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Learn</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <aside class="sidebar">sidebar</aside>
      <main class="main">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="box box1">1</div>
          <div class="box box2">2</div>
          <div class="box box3">3</div>
          <div class="box box4">4</div>
          <div class="box box2">5</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
    

  </body>
</html>



In the flex-container the five elements go beyond the horizontal viewport, that's because of the 1fr value set on grid-template-columns in grid-container. If I remove the grid-container the flex items won't go more than the available viewport in mobile portrait view. I don't think using flex-wrap is the proper solution.
I would be grateful for any suggestion
UPDATE: I fixed it by using minmax(0, 1fr) intead of just 1fr on the grid-container.
